# Changing my control state after binding repeater with other ObjectDataSourceID

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this weird problem on my blog site(WIP) which I haven't found a solution for.  I have a repeater who gets all the articles from a SQL database with a `ObjectDataSourceID` called `dsGetArticles`.

What I want to do is when someone clicks a article, I change the `ObjectDataSourceID` to `dsGetArticle`. So far so good,everything works, i see 1 article instead of all the articles.

Now after I checked if the user is logged in , I wanna add/remove editing functionality so if the user is not logged in, obviously he is not allowed to change the article nor the comments from it.

So when the page loads and the user isn't logged in, I set the panel with edit functions invisible.That works,but as soon as he clicks the article (not a postback) the edit functions become visible again even though it went through the code behind and made the panel invisible.

The problem only occurs when I change the `ObjectDataSourceID` and databind it.

This is my codebehind for this:
(standard the Panel is visible)

```
if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["articleID"] != null)
            {
                repArticles.DataSourceID = "dsGetArticle";
            }
            else
            {
                repArticles.DataSourceID = "dsGetArticles";
            }
            repArticles.DataBind();
        }
        if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            foreach (RepeaterItem ri in repArticles.Items)
            {
                Panel pnlArticleFunctions = ri.FindControl("pnlArticleFunctions") as Panel;
                pnlArticleFunctions.Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

I have tried using a `Linkbutton` as well so I could do it with a postback but I got the same result, no Panels are invisible :

```
protected void lbLink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        repArticles.DataSourceID = "dsGetArticle";
        repArticles.DataBind();
        foreach (RepeaterItem ri in repArticles.Items)
        {
            Panel pnlTest = ri.FindControl("pnlTest") as Panel;
            pnlTest.Visible = false;
        }
         //doesnt become invisible
    }
```

Comment: In what event do you have the `if (!IsPostBack){}` part? onInit, onLoad, onPreRender?

Answer (score 0):

aside from the second code block that you placed, Are you sure that the `if(!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)` part isn't in the `if(!IsPostBack)` block? because from what you say it seems like the `IsAuthenticated` part was executed only if is not postback.

Comment: yes actually those are 2 examples i gave, in the first everything happens in the pageload method without postbacks since i work with a <a href> element wich doesnt trigger postbacks.In de second example i work with a Linkbutton who triggers a postback and then i put my code in the event of the Linkbutton.It doesnt matter even without the authentication check i cannot change the state of the control.

Comment: first of all for anything to happen 'without post back' as you call it there would have to be some client side logic, which we obviously are not talking about. It's most probable that the code that you think is running isn't actually happening. put a breakpoint in the foreach loop and check whether the app even enters it.. also check: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: i have checked the loop ,he go's in ,runs the code,finds the controls and put visible = false.Controls stays visible....It only happens when i change the ObjectDataSourceID to something else,if i rebind it to the same source,it works.But thats not what i want ofc.